# CSRF protection causing "Type mismatch error"

Tags: javascript, django, csrf, satchmo

In the Satchmo code (satchmo/satchmo/apps/satchmo_store/contact/templates/contact/_state_js.html) the following JavaScript is causing errors in Internet Explorer version 6:

```
/**
* Required for Django's CSRF protection when using AJAX
* Taken from here - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/
*/

$('html').ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

Specifically the following line is referenced by IE:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
```

The problem occurs in a form which contains "Country" and "Province". Obviously if the Country changes, then the available Provinces must change. As soon as the user selects a Country, Explorer reports this error:

```
Line: 239
Char: 9
Error: Type mismatch
Code: 0
URL: http://10.1.1.7:8000/checkout/
```

Can anyone suggest what the problem is here? I don't really understand why it should be a "Type mismatch" either?

Many thanks, Thomas

Comment: And what about other versions of IE?

Comment: I'm getting this error on IE 8.  The type mismatch happens on the call to xhr.setRequestHeader, at the start of the line.